# Is it against Xbox Live policy to play on multiple accounts?

Tags: xbox-network

On a policy level, does Xbox Live oppose the notion of a single player owning and operating multiple accounts in multiplayer games, especially PVP multiplayer games such as Overwatch, Fortnite, Apex, Halo, Call of Duty, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft publish a general purpose [Services Agreement](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/servicesagreement) which covers all services offered by Microsoft including Xbox Live.

It includes a Code of Conduct section that links out to an Xbox Live specific interpretation called the [Xbox Community Standards](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/legal/community-standards).

I recommend reading both documents carefully and interpreting them for yourself.

However, I think the most relevant part is in the Xbox Community Standards where there is a section entitled [Harmful behavior has no place on Xbox](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/legal/community-standards#vii); we are expected not to "use multiple profiles to unfairly manipulate your multiplayer rank".